# Get value from DataGrid.SelectedItems IList

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am creating a WPF application that displays the records, from a single SQL database table, in a DataGrid.  The application also includes a TreeView that is used to filter records as well as three buttons that:

1. Delete all records.
2. Delete records that are older than 30 minutes.
3. Delete records that are selected in the DataGrid.

I have been instructed to use code behind and not MVVM so my DataGrid binding takes place on the various events such as Window_Loaded, "TreeViewItem"_Selected, etc... and everything is working correctly.  As for the buttons, the first one is straight forward since it deletes all of the records from the table so I am simply sending a string with the TSQL command.  The second button is essentially the same however it is executing a stored procedure.  The third button and the final piece to this application is where I'm stuck.

Obviously I need to "match" the rows that were selected in the DataGrid to rows in the database table which I can do using the record ID however the challenge I am faced with is that I cannot figure out how to pull the record ID from the selected items list.  I have been scouring the internet for nearly a week now and nearly all of the information I find references DataGridView which according to XAML is not supported.  I created the following method

```
    private void GetSelectedRecordIds()
    {
        var selectedRows = licenseGrid.SelectedItems;
    }
```

and this returns an IList with the indexes and each index shows the values in that row (screenshot of locals below).

[image]

Is this the right way to go about this?
If so, what is the best way to pull the value I need from the "Id" column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are populating your DataGrid by binding its ItemsCollection to a collection of custom objects , you can cast your IList back to an IEnumerable of strongly-typed object like this:

```
private void GetSelectedRecordIds()
{
    IList selectedRows = (IList)licenseGrid.SelectedItems;
    var stronglyTypedList = selectedRows.Cast<MyType>();

    foreach (MyType m in stronglyTypedList)
    {
        int id = m.ID;
        // do something with ID
    }
}
```

If you need additional help deleting from the database based on those IDs, let me know...